# CSS: move button to left

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here is my current UI:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I would like to move the red button shown in the picture to the left side of the input. So far I've tried adding a `margin-left` property but that did not work. Does anyone have a suggestion on how to get the button to move to the left? I'd like to have it aligned with the bottom input field.

Comment: Please show a [mcve] for us to troubleshoot faster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was easier than I thought, instead of adding margin-left I added margin-right: 20px and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Put

```
style="position:absolute"
```

to your button, you will be able to move with `Left` after that.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap 3 has a control called a [Input Group](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups). You can use it like this:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
</div>
```

Note: To move the button to the left or right, simply move the `<input>` above or below the `<div class="input-group-btn">`

Comment: this moves the button to extreme left or extreme right. I want to move the button little left so that it gets aligned with the right border of the input

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
      </span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
    </div><!-- /input-group -->
  </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
```